# min-height on inline-block not working

Tags: css

Why is this `div` element clipping the content? It should fit the content

http://jsfiddle.net/ojfxtwdv/

```
<div>
    text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>
    text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>
</div>

div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: remove `height:200px;` [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ojfxtwdv/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set a `min-height` of `200px` but also set a `height` of `200px` which kind of renders the `min-height` pointless.  If you remove the `height` the content will fit.

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    /* height: 200px; Remove this */
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```